# Selective ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH error with multiple Apache-hosted sites

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have several hostnames running on Apache for which I'd like to have specific strong TLS configuration. There are 2 `.conf` files enabled in Apache: the first one contains all the VirtualHosts for port 80 (say `default.conf`) and the other one stores respective VirtualHosts for port 443 (`default443.conf`).

It is possible to access only the hostname from the very first VirtualHost of `default.conf` via https://. All remaining hosts are throwing *ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH* in any web browser. When accessing such a failing hostname via `curl`, the below error appears:

> curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

`default.conf`:

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example2.com
ServerAlias www.example2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example2.com$1 [R=301,L]
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`default443.conf`:

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
RewriteEngine on
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd ECDHParameters secp384r1
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves secp384r1
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/example.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/example.key
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example2.com
ServerAlias www.example2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example2
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example2\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example2.com$1 [R=301,L]
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/example2.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/example2.key
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"
</VirtualHost>

SSLProtocol             -all +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite          -all:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
SSLSessionTickets       off

SSLUseStapling On
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_stapling(32768)"
```

According to the above configuration, example.com is properly resolving via https:// using the cipher suites declared while SSL handshake is failing for example2.com.

In case of commenting our the `SSLCipherSuite` directive or replacing the cipher suites with the ones [suggested by Mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS#Intermediate_compatibility_.28recommended.29) for TLS 1.2, example2.com starts working properly via https:// as well.

> apachectl -v
>   Server version: Apache/2.4.41
>
> openssl version
>   OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019

I would like to clear out the reason why only one hostname is functioning properly via https:// while the remaining ones keep getting failed SSL handshakes with `ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305` ciphers declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution appeared to be pretty obvious after some research.

There was ECDSA SSL/TLS certificate installed for the hostname working properly (`example.com` from the listings) while all the other hosts had certificates with RSA private keys installed for them.

As the declared cipher suites were ECDSA-authentication only ([1](https://ciphersuite.info/cs/TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256/)) ([2](https://ciphersuite.info/cs/TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384/)) the handshake was failing for hosts with RSA private keys.

Reissuing the remaining certs with EC keys solved the issue.